# ¿Cómo enviar formulario (Método Get) al cambiar la selección de elemento Select HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

¿Cómo puedo hacer para enviar un formulario con el Change Event de un elemento Select HTML?
**(sin usar AJAX)**

Ahora lo estoy haciendo al hacer Click en un botón **(elemento del tipo Submit)**.
*Lo que quiero hacer es quitar el botón y sustituir su accion en el evento change del elemento Select*

Mi código HTML:

```
  <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Punteo", "Apuntes", FormMethod.Get))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <label>Empresas</label>

            <select id="empresas"></select>

            <input type="hidden" id="idEmpresa" name="idEmpresa" value="@ViewBag.IdEmpresa" />

            <input type="submit" id="getEmpresa" name="getEmpresa" value="Buscar" />
        }
    </div>
```

Mi Código JS:

```
$("#empresas").change(function () {
    var valor = $("#empresas option:selected").val();
    $("#empresa").val(valor);
    $("#idEmpresa").val(valor);
    
     **AQUI EL CODIGO QUE NESECITO**
});
```

Comment: ¿Quieres cambiar el método del elemento form al cambiar el valor del select? Es que quizá no me quedó claro

Comment: No es cambiar el valor seleccionado, es enviar el formulario (como si hubieras hecho click sobre el boton)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si no he entendido mal, sería simplemente añadir un id al formulario y luego ejecutar la acción submit de ese formulario. Algo así:

```
  <div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Punteo", "Apuntes", FormMethod.Get, new { @id="frmPunteo"}))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <label>Empresas</label>

        <select id="empresas"></select>

        <input type="hidden" id="idEmpresa" name="idEmpresa" value="@ViewBag.IdEmpresa" />

        <input type="submit" id="getEmpresa" name="getEmpresa" value="Buscar" />
    }
</div>
```

Y luego el JS:

```
$("#empresas").change(function () {
    var valor = $("#empresas option:selected").val();
    $("#empresa").val(valor);
    $("#idEmpresa").val(valor);
    
     $("#frmPunteo").submit();
});
```